# pycharm matplotlib macOS не получается установить

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается установить matplotlib в PyCharm на macOS

Answer (score 2):

gcc запускается, но вылетает с ошибкой, что он не находит файл  "ft2build.h":

```
fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found
```

Это файл от библиотеки freetype 2. Или она у вас не установлена, или gcc не знает, где ее искать.

Answer (score 0):

OS Вам явно говорит, что нет `gcc`

[Установите](https://www.mkyong.com/mac/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-mac-os-x/) `gcc`

Comment: перед этим он настойчиво попросил меня установить gcc на что я дал своё согласие, попробую сделать это самостоятельно

Comment: @hedgehogues Вообще то ошибка не об этом, а об отсутствии "ft2build.h"